# Create a dictionary with specific pairs from other dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

This list:

```
data=[[{'t1':'text1.txt','date1':'class1'}],[{'t2':'text2.txt','date2':'class2'}]]
data
```

gives

```
[[{'t1': 'text1.txt', 'date1': 'class1'}],
 [{'t2': 'text2.txt', 'date2': 'class2'}]]
```

and I want to turn it into this:
**EDIT** brackets added

```
[[{'text1.txt': 'class1'}], [{'text2.txt': 'class2'}]]
```

which means:

to create a list where each sublist inside, will be comprised of a dictionary where the **key** would be the **value** of the first dictionary in the first sublist and the **value** would be the **value** of the second dictionary of the first sublist and so on for the following sublists.

My attempt was this:

```
se=[]
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        jk=j.values()
        se.append(jk)
se
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to create a dictionary containing one `key`:`value` pair per input dictionary? Every input dictionary will have two key:value pairs?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through each dictionary in nested list and create a tuple from `values()` method for each dictionary like this `tuple(dict.values())`. After converting to tuple you can use `dict()` to create dictionary from the tuple like this `dict([tuple(dict.values())])`

> **Note:** If your dictionary has exactly two keys then only it will work.

```
res = [[dict([tuple(d.values())]) for d in lst]for lst in data]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[{'text1.txt': 'class1'}], [{'text2.txt': 'class2'}]]
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake. I forgot the brackets. This is the needed result: `[[{'text1.txt': 'class1'}], [{'text2.txt': 'class2'}]]`

Comment: Can you modify your answer to give the above result? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data=[[{'t1':'text1.txt','date1':'class1'}],[{'t2':'text2.txt','date2':'class2'}]]

all_vals = [];

for i in data:
    for j in i:
        for key in j:
            all_vals.append(j[key])

new_list = [];            
for i in range(0,len(all_vals)-1):
    if (i % 2) == 0:
        new_dict = {};
        new_dict = {all_vals[i]:all_vals[i+1]}
        new_list.append(new_dict)
    else:
        continue
        
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'text1.txt': 'class1'}, {'text2.txt': 'class2'}]
```

This code works regardless of the length of your list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does most of the job. You can add another line to get the desired results:

```
In [108]: se
Out[108]: [dict_values(['text1.txt', 'class1']), dict_values(['text2.txt', 'class2'])]

In [109]: [[{list(x)[0]:list(x)[1]} for x in se]]
Out[109]: [[{'text1.txt': 'class1'}, {'text2.txt': 'class2'}]]
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake. I forgot the brackets. This is the needed result: [[{'text1.txt': 'class1'}], [{'text2.txt': 'class2'}]]

Comment: This should do the job: `In [128]: [[{list(x)[0]:list(x)[1]}] for x in se]  
Out[128]: [[{'text1.txt': 'class1'}], [{'text2.txt': 'class2'}]]`

Answer (score 0):

The following function should convert the inputs to the outputs you requested.

```
def convert_to_list_of_list_of_dictionaries(input_dictionaries):
  ret_dictionaries = []
  for inp in input_dictionaries:
    k, v = inp[0].values()
    ret_dictionaries.append({k, v})
  return ret_dictionaries
```

However, there are a few things going on with the input/outputs that are little concerning and make the data harder to work with.
On the input side, the data is being wrapped in an extra list that in this context, does not provide any function, and forces you to index the first element of the inner list to access the dict `k, v = inp[0].values()`. On the output side, we're doing the same thing, which makes it harder to iterate over the outputs. It would look something like:

```
# psuedocode
for kv in reformatted_outputs:
    unwrapped_dict = kv[0]
    key, value = next(iter(unwrapped_dict.items()))
    # process key and value
```

instead, if you had an output format like ``{'text1.txt': 'class1', 'text2.txt': 'class2'}`, you could process data like:

```
key, value in reformatted_outputs.items():
    # process key and value
```

If you have the ability to modify the inputs and outputs of what you're working on, this could save you some trouble, and anyone you're working with some head scratches.

If you wanted to modify the output format, your function could look something like:

```
def convert_to_single_dictionary(input_dictionaries):
  ret = {}
  for inp in input_dictionaries:
    print(inp)
    # it looks like the input data is being wrapped in an extra list
    k, v = inp[0].values()
    ret[k] = v
  return ret
```

Hope this is helpful and thanks for asking the question!

Comment: sorry for the mistake. I forgot the brackets. This is the needed result: [[{'text1.txt': 'class1'}], [{'text2.txt': 'class2'}]]